# V3022 False Positive

Tags: c#, pvs-studio

PVS Studio throws V3022: Expression 'list.Count > 1' is always false. Program.cs 20

```
public class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        var list = new List<string>();
        var keyvaluelist = new List<(string, string)>() { ("1", "2"), ("3", "4") };

        list.Add(DateTime.Now.ToString());

        foreach ((string Key, string Value) in keyvaluelist)
            list.Add(DateTime.Now.ToString());

        if (list.Count > 1)                    
            Console.WriteLine(list.Count);
    }
}
```

Is this a false positive?

Comment: It seems like you've just proven so, yes

Comment: `keyvaluelist` contains 2 values. You iterate it and do two adds to `list`. Plus the first add of the current time. So there should be three elements in `list`.

Comment: There are three elements and I'd assume PVS Studio fails to understand the old-new Tuples mechanic.

Comment: Stack Overflow is the wrong place to create a bug report, if that is your intention. Try it here: https://www.viva64.com/en/about-feedback/

Comment: While this is "why it is not working" and provided a MCVE, this question is self-explanatory and unlikely to help anyone (like, print("$1",2+2) and stating that it will output '4' and asking if that's OK). It seems to be a bug report that belongs elsewhere and will be outdated shortly after the bug is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This indeed looks like a false positive. We'll investigate it further and fix it in one of the future releases.

Also, as was mentioned in the comments before, false-positive reports are not the right format of questions for stackoverflow, so you can send them directly to PVS-Studio support at support@viva64.com or https://www.viva64.com/en/about-feedback/.

Thanks for your feedback!